# Is it possible to play 360 video on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am curious if it would be possible to play 360 video on a Raspberry Pi. 
So far I have had no luck loading any YouTube 360 videos - they play but not in 360 (all I get is a distorted video)

Would the latest Raspberry plust a specific build of the OS be of any help?

Comment: 360 video is not "special" in any way, it's just distorted in a way where the vr display can un-distort. That being said it's uasually at a much higher resolution. So and raspberry pi may struggle with that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a second gen Pi, so I can't comment on the newer ones, but mine does struggle with 1080p and especially 4k at times, so I'd be suprised if it could handle 360 videos with a decent resolution for VR.